# How to open the React Native connection with SQLcipher

Tags: android, react-native, android-sqlite, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I am using the below command to add the lib 
1.NPM install

npm install --save react-native-sqlcipher-storage

> npm ERR! code E404
>   npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-native-sqlcipher-storage@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dasaraa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-06-27T13_34_4
6_011Z-debug.log